# Get the page number of a table in tabula-py

Tags: python, tabula-py

Currently, I am using tabula to collect tables from a PDF document.

```
tables = tabula.read_pdf(file,pages='all')
```

I would like to know which page the tables are on. For example, for tables[0] it's on page 1, tables[1] page 3, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you solve this inside tabula-py?

Answer (score 1):

```
import tabula

pdf_file = "file_name.pdf"

def extract_tables_from_page(pdf_file, page_number):
    tables = tabula.read_pdf(pdf_file, pages=page_number)
    if tables:
      return True
    else:
      return False


all_tables_with_page_numbers = [page_number for page_number in range(1, total_pdf_pages + 1) if extract_tables_from_page(pdf_file, page_number)]

print(all_tables_with_page_numbers)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).